# Difference between 'return' and 'pure'

Tags: haskell

What is the difference between `return` and  `pure` from `Control.Applicative` ? It seems that I can use `pure` even at the end of a `do` block?

So is there any situation where one should be preferred over the other (besides that everyone expects a `return` at the end of a `do` Block)?

Comment: There is no difference, they both exist for historical reasons (`Monad` has not always been a superclass of `Applicative`). There is a proposal to alias `return` to `pure`.

Comment: To clarify, they are only the same if you know you are dealing with a `Monad`. `pure` is more general than `return` in that it returns an `Applicative` so you can't replace all instances of `return` with `pure` but you can replace `pure` with `return`.

Comment: @Lee, I think it's the other way around in your second sentence.

Comment: Relevant proposal and discussion on reddit from today, coincidentally: https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/3mb8lb/monad_of_no_return_proposal_mrp/

Comment: Some authors have pointed out that a less powerful algebra (in this case Applicative) can be better for a given application if the more powerful algebra (in this case monad) is overkill. (Reasons include clarifying intent, highlighting what really matters, discouraging creep, etc.) If that is true, does it make sense to keep both functions?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

In GHC 7.8 and before, `Applicative` was not a superclass of `Monad`. It was even possible for a `Monad` instance to not have an `Applicative` instance. There was, however, an expectation that `pure` and `return` should have the same behavior for types that are instances of both.

In GHC 7.10, due to the [Functor-Applicative-Monad Proposal](https://wiki.haskell.org/Functor-Applicative-Monad_Proposal), `Applicative` is now a superclass of `Monad` (`class Applicative m => Monad m`) and it is now a rule that `pure` and `return` must be the same for all `Monad` instances. In fact, the default implementation of `return` is now `pure`, as seen in [the source on hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#return).

`pure` might be preferred to `return` because it does not incur a `Monad` constraint, only an `Applicative` constraint, thus making the function more general. `return` might be preferred to `pure` in do notation because of historical precedent, but `pure` could be used to exactly the same effect.

Answer (score 29):

The Applicative typeclass was added after `Monad` and historically the `Monad` class has not been a subclass of `Applicative`. This was changed fairly recently in the `Applicative-Monad-Proposal` and this means that `return a` should be equivalent to `pure a` for every `Monad` instance.

There is a [proposal](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.haskell.libraries/25274) to move `return` out of the `Monad` class and make it an alias for `pure`.

Therefore when dealing with a `Monad` you should always be able to use `pure` instead of `return`. You cannot go the other way however since `pure` has a more general type than `return` since it only returns an `Applicative`. For example the following

```
wontCheck :: Applicative f => f Int
wontCheck = return 4
```

won't type check since `return` requires `f` to be a `Monad`.